# Show image next to text using CSS/Bootstrap and django jinja 2

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-5

i want to show image next to text. But its showing below it
Here is the code

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>This is my first post</h1>
            <div> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard …   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="/media/post/Screenshot_from_2022-07-17_23-55-13.png" class="img-thumbnail" >
        </div>
        <div><a href="/blog/first-post" >Read More..</a></div>
        
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>this is second post</h1>
            <div> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard …   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="/media/post/0a61bddab956.png" class="img-thumbnail" >
        </div>
        <div><a href="/blog/2nd-post" >Read More..</a></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

This is how it look like
[image]

EDIT. I copied this from view-source and some text is cut off there. Actually i am using Django jina 2 template code

```
{% for post in context %}
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h1>{{ post.title}}</h1>
    {{ post.content |truncatewords:20 | safe}}   
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="/media/{{post.image}}" class="img-thumbnail" >
</div>
<div><a href="/blog/{{post.slug}}" >Read More..</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is base.html file code

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">
{%block content %}

{%endblock%}
  </div> 
</div>
```

I think `truncatewords:20` is causing the issue.

Replacing it with `truncatewords_html:20` resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `d-inline` class on image and text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `HTML Code` you didn't close the `div` of `class col-md-8`

Check now the code in large screen the text and image are next to each others

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h1>This is my first post</h1>
      <div>
        <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard …
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="/media/post/Screenshot_from_2022-07-17_23-55-13.png" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div><a href="/blog/first-post">Read More..</a></div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>this is second post</h1>
        <div>
          <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard …
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="/media/post/0a61bddab956.png" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div><a href="/blog/2nd-post">Read More..</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `class="row"` should not hold `col` sum greater than 12. Reformat your code like below.

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>This is my first post</h1>
            <div> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard …   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="/media/post/Screenshot_from_2022-07-17_23-55-13.png" class="img-thumbnail" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><a href="/blog/first-post" >Read More..</a></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>this is second post</h1>
            <div> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard …   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="/media/post/0a61bddab956.png" class="img-thumbnail" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><a href="/blog/2nd-post" >Read More..</a></div>
</div>
```